# Creating a RAID 1 with 4TB hardrives in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, raid-1

I have the following set up:

- Motherboard: Asrock B450M Pro4
- 1 NVM Samsung 250GB (for OS)
- 2 identical 4TB Seagate HDH
- and windows 10 pro

My intention is to mount the 2 4TB in a Raid 1 configuration.

I came across the following problems:

Option 1, directly on the motherboard: If I use the AMD Raid controller option of the bios and set a new Raid 1 array then in the windows disk administration I see two 4TB HD anyway.

Option 2, if I disable the raid from the bios and try to do it directly in windows using the space administrator option I get and error message saying that there's another application using the harddrives and it needs to be closed (no other app is open, it happens from a fresh start)

Any idea on what's going on and what should be better (bios or OS). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I see we have that same motherbord. Are you try to update bios to the newest version? Maybe there is an issue. I have some problem with old bios on this motherboard long time ago.
You can also install linux on another partition/drive or use live version and check if there is also that same problem with create raid. If no, something is wrong with this windows instalation.